# Firebase short link not working when copy pasting out of the docs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

```
Task shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLink(Uri.parse("My link"))
                .setDynamicLinkDomain("sadfe.app.goo.gl")
                .buildShortDynamicLink()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Short link created
                            Uri shortLink = (Uri) task.getResult();
                            Uri flowchartLink = (Uri) task.getResult();
                        } else {
                            // Error
                            System.out.println("Error");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I've added internet permissions to the Android manifest, any idea what is going wrong and the onCompleted method is never fired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who does come across this issue, what fixed the problem was updating to the latest emulators and Google Play services.

Comment: Updating google play services fix my problem. Thanks.